# How to restrict from sending null values into Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to do a validation in firebase. However, even when I left the field blank and click submit, the null value is still submitted. How do I validate or change any security in a way that it will restrict any null values from saving into the database?

```
function save() {
    window.location = 'profile.html';

    var email = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;
    var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value
    var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value
    var occupation = document.getElementById('TypeSelect').value

    //One of the validation example
    var name;
    name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    if (name == "") {
        alert("Please enter your name");
    };

    var data = {
        User_id: uid,
        Name: name,
        Address: address,
        Phone: phone,
        Email: email,
        Occupation: occupation,
    }

    var updates = {};
    updates['/users/' + uid] = data;
    firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to only put items in `data` if they have a value:

```
var data = {};
if (uid) data.User_id = uid;
if (name) data.Name = name
if (address) data.Address = address;
if (phone) data.Phone = phone;
if (email) data.Email = email;
if (occupation) data.Occupation = occupation;
```